# How to access YML file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml, enumerize

I have set up a settings.yml file in my config folder with some list elements I want to pass to my enumerize in my rails model :

```
config/ settings.yml
enumerize:
  hotel_status:
    - "Hotel Privé"
    - "Bâtiment Publique"
    - "CHRS"
    - "CADA"
    - "Centre d'accueil"
    - "Camping"
    - "Autres"
```

I am trying to pass the list inside my Hotel model to enumerize this way :

```
  enumerize :status, in: Settings.enumerize.hotel_status
```

but I am getting `uninitialized constant Hotel::Settings`

How can I pass the list in the YML to enumerize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem called [config](https://github.com/railsconfig/config), you can do it without hassle plus you can add multi-environment settings to your app.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an initializer in config/initialize, perhaps `load_settings.rb`

```
require 'yaml'
settings = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'settings.yml')
EnumerizedValues = OpenStruct(settings['enumerize'])
```

You can then do

```
enumerize :status in: EnumerizedValues.hotel_status
```